# "Gravity, even if weak, must apply in the microworld"

Tags: gravity

So I was just watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbPWYjnQIO8) and at [1:42](https://youtu.be/CbPWYjnQIO8?t=1m42s) he mentions, "If all we had to go on was the data from particle physics experiments, we wouldn't even know gravity existed."

Then at [2:23](https://youtu.be/CbPWYjnQIO8?t=2m23s) - "Gravity, even if weak, must apply in the microworld. That's not a very profound thought, but it's true."

Might be a stupid question, but I don't see why he's so confident that that would be true. I'm just curious about the reason, especially since he mentioned that detecting gravity effects in quantum-scale experiments is impossible ([1:33](https://youtu.be/CbPWYjnQIO8?t=1m33s)).

Comment: Macroscopic objects are made up of lots of microscopic objects.  If gravity does not apply to microscopic objects it would seem very odd that it would apply to large collections of them.

Answer (score 0):

> "detecting gravity effects in quantum-scale experiments is impossible"

This is a dubious statement. For example, "quantum-mechanical phase shift of neutrons caused by their interaction with the Earth’s gravitational field" was experimentally observed. See, e.g., http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/14/5/055010/pdf ( Hartmut Abele and Helmut Leeb 2012 New J. Phys. 14 055010) and references there.

Comment: While not irrelevant, I don't see how this answers the core of the question as asked.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty : it does confirm that gravity applies in the microworld (see the title of the question).